# How do I parse this with peg grammar?

Tags: parsing, peg, pegjs

I'm trying to make a parser using [pegjs](http://pegjs.majda.cz/). I need to parse something like:

```
blah blah START Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit END foo bar 
etc.
```

I have trouble writing the rule to catch the text from `"START"` to `"END"`.

Comment: Is it possible to split .pegjs grammar into several files and import one into another?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use negative lookahead predicates:

```
phrase
  =(!"START" .)* "START" result:(!"END" .)* "END" .* {
    for (var i=0;i<result.length;++i)
      // remove empty element added by predicate matching
      {result[i]=result[i][1];
      }
    return result.join("");
   }
```

You need to use a negative predicate for END as well as START because repetition in pegjs is greedy.

<s>Alternatively, the action could be written as</s>

```
{return result.join("").split(',').join("");}
```

Although this relies on not-necessarily documented behavior of `join` when dealing with nested arrays (namely that it joins the sub-arrays with commas and then concatenates them).

[UPDATE] A shorter way to deal with the empty elements is

```
phrase
  =(!"START" .)* "START" result:(t:(!"END" .){return t[1];})* "END" .* {
      return result.join("");
    }
```